# Nested reactive forms within Mat Table cant find control

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to build a form within a table using both reactive forms and the material table.

I'd like to allow users to add a row to the table, and then edit it, so inside my main FormGroup (there are other fields except those in the table), I've put a FormArray which on click adds itself an inner form group. 
That FormGroup has several FormControls within in such a way where each row is an independent FormGroup and has its own controls.

Since each row is created dynamically, I couldn't give names to that form groups, so I've used the Material Table index to try to access the form groups.

My problem is that the inner control is not found ("Error: Cannot find control with name XXX"), I'm guessing I made it terribly more complex than it should be, so I'd like your advice on how to go about it.

html

```
<form [formGroup]="contaningFG">
  <some other forms...>
  <button (click)="addRow">Add row</button>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

        <!-- First Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="FirstColumn">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> FirstColumn </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [formControlName]="myFirstFC">
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Second Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="SecondColumn">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Second Column </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [formControlName]="mySecondFC">
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"
          [formGroup]="innerFA.controls[i]"></tr>
  </table>
</from>
```

ts

```
public containingFG = new FormGroup({
  "foo": new FormControl(),
  "bar": new FormControl(true),
});
public innerFA = new FormArray([]);

public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<AbstractControl>;
public displayedColumns = [
  "FirstColumn",
  "SecondColumn"
]

constructor() {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.containingFG.addControl("innerForms", this.innerFA);
  this.dataSource.data = this.innerFA.controls;
}

addRow() {
  this.customersForm.push(new FormGroup({
    "firstColumn": new FormControl("hi"),
    "secondColumn": new FormControl("hello")
  }));
  this.customersDataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your `mat-table` I think you require a FormGroup with a FormArray control which has FormGroups (those are the controls in your table row).

Something like:

```
const group = new FormGroup( {
  rows: new FormArray( [
    new FormGroup( {
      foo: new FormControl(1),
      bar: new FormControl(1)
    } ),
    new FormGroup( {
      foo: new FormControl(2),
      bar: new FormControl(2)
    })
  ])
} );
```

Of course you can make a function that creates your Row FormGroup structure for you.

```
<div [formGroup]="group" class="mat-elevation-z1" #tableWrapper>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" formArrayName="rows">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="foo">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Foo</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">

        <mat-form-field class="input">
          <input matInput formControlName="foo">
        </mat-form-field>
     </td>
   </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="bar">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Bar</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">

        <mat-form-field class="input">
          <input matInput formControlName="bar">
        </mat-form-field>
     </td>
   </ng-container>


   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns; let i = index"></tr>
</table>
```

Finally you need to add in your data:

```
const data = [
{ foo: 1, bar: 1 },
{ foo: 2, bar: 2 },
]
```

If I am correct, the data you pass into the `mat-table` needs to be present in your FormArray structure, so you have to patch the values. I think the function of the datasource is to print values in each `mat-cell`, using the `row` variable. 
However since you are using a formControl you can either use `[value]="row.foo"` in to set the value, or you pre-fill it when you create your form structure.

An example by Google that might help:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-riepzk-rp5jbf?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Disclaimer: I have not tested this code, but it should be about right.
Hope it helps!